# ReactNative: как передать компонент для отрисовки?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Стоит такая задача: передать компонент в компонент, что бы вывести его с нужными параметрами в цикле. Подробнее: есть массив данных

```
[{id: 1, value: 'Apple'}, {id: 2, value: 'Orange'}, {id: 3, 'Chery'}]
```

Есть неким компонент, который делает отрисовку полученного массива:

```
const CustomList = ({arr}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {
                 arr.map(item => {
                     return (<View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>)
                 })
            }
        </View>
    )

}
```

Структура массива будет одна и та же, а вот вид может меняться. Поэтому решил сделать, что бы вот эта часть

```
return (<View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>)
```

передавалась как параметр. Только вот не хватает знаний, что бы понять, как это сделать, гугление не помогло.

Как мне правильно передать компонент и вызвать его с параметрами?

Дополнение: мне нужно, что бы я мог передать компонент в компонент, то есть сделать такой вызов

```
<CustomList arr=[] template=<View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>>
```

А сам компонент переписать так

```
const CustomList = ({arr, template}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {
                 arr.map(item => {
                     return template // вот как тут подставить данные?
                 })
            }
        </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: там где `template` сущность почему вы не хотите там вернуть массив компонент? Я понимаю, что у вас различные шаблоны (template) могут быть, так каждый компонент и можно "переключать" в самом компоненте

Comment: вы имеете ввиду, перебирать их через switch или if?

Comment: вообще для более сложных вещей можно и `useReducer`  использовать. Для ваших целей я бы взял просто switch и через props прокидывал значение, относительно которого бы работала бы логика. Все зависит от задачи, как всегда

Comment: Перечитал дополненый вопрос и вошел в ступор. Мои сомнения: в функцию `CustomList` вы передаете два параметра. Первый - массив, второй - шаблон. Вот этот шаблон (`template`) что содержит? Ведь то что у вас написано не реально по логике, так как `item.value` при вызове не существует, и появится только при рендере `CustomList`

Comment: https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel - тут при вызове есть параметр renderItem. вот я точно так же хочу)

Comment: Так мой ответ абсолютно идентичен. Только у меня функциональные компоненты (так и у вас функциональный), а там классовый. И различие в том, что `props` передается по отдельности, я не одной переменной:) больше я различий не вижу

Comment: как у вашем примере вызвать NeedsComponent, что бы передать в него вот эту часть - <View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что правильней всего это создать отдельный компонент под вот эту директиву

```js
<View><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>
```

то есть

```js
const NeedsComponent = (props) => {
 // в действительности здесь можно все что угодно прописывать, и том числе 
 // и манипуляциии с props, state, функции
  return(
    <View><Text>{props.value}</Text></View>
  )
}
```

И далее формировать список элементов, основываясь на компонентах `NeedsComponent`

```js
........
                 arr.map(item => {
                     return (<NeedsComponent value={item.value} />)
                 })
........
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я наверно не верно сформировал вопрос. дополнил, посмотрите